# Which conversion pattern specifier would give me 2 digit dates in log4cxx?

Tags: log4j, log4cxx

I am trying to use:

```
    <layout class="PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{MM/dd/yy-HH:mm:ss}-t@%t-Inf-%m%n" />
    </layout>
```

but I am still getting a full 4 digit year. Is anybody familiar with getting 2 digit dates?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No luck here. It seems this part was hastily translated from Java's `SimpleDateFormat` so that it only handles 0-padding and never truncates the number:

```cpp
NumericToken::format() {
// ...
  if ( initialLength + width > finalLength )
  {
    s.insert( initialLength, ( initialLength + width ) - finalLength, (logchar) 0x30 /* '0' */);
  }
}
```